# bot initiated group conversations on Skype

Tags: skype, botframework, skype-for-business, skypedeveloper, botconnector

I'm looking for a way to create a **bot initiated** group conversations with *MS botframework* on **Skype** channel (or Skype for Business although there is no channel for it :).

From researching so far in BotBuilder C# space far [looks like the only channel officially supporting it is "Email channel"](https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/csharp/builder/sdkreference/routing.html).

**The question is, does any one knows an alternative way?**

Comment: You can may be read this ..https://support.skype.com/en/faq/FA34698/can-i-add-skype-bots-to-a-group-conversation

Comment: @peaceUser, Thanks! However, I look for the different function: a way for a bot to add users to group